# Not to bind culture from browser automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, localization

I have a web form page and want to set language from code behide using resource files and the meta in label control. Parameter is from somewhere else.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="" meta:resourcekey="lblTitle"></asp:Label>
```

However, in this way (meta), it will read the preferred language from browser and set the cultural automatically. For example, if the perfered language from broswer is en-AU, then it will starting reading info from my recourse file xxxx.aspx.en-AU.resx.
I don't want it that way as I want to control everything manually.I have to explicitly handle this from code behind.

Can I turn off this auto-binding from the browser?

Answer (score 2):

In web.config, you can force a specific culture for your application. For `en-US`, you can use this.

Web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en" uiCulture="en-US"/>
    ...
  </system.web>
```

In your code-behind, you can then override at will using:

```
var lang = "en-AU";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
```